# How to transfer data without using props between components in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-binding, react-props, virtual-dom

Hi Stack overflow users,
As i am working in the reactjs from several days , one question is there in my mind like is there a way /ways to transfer data between components in react.js and even at some time i thought like how the one way data binding gives high performance in react and how virtual DOM updated the real DOM internally? I request some one to help me regarding this?

Comment: you can use react context api [right here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Hi @RedaMeskali can you please tell me with a sample instance, then that will be more helpful ....

Comment: here is a very [detailed example](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-the-new-react-context-api-fce011e7d87)

Comment: Thank you so much @RedaMeskali  ..can you please give some ideas over how the one way data binding gives high performance in react and how virtual DOM updated the real DOM internally ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use global context API for this 
[take a look at this](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext)

or use REDUX for that
[image]
it helps you to pass states to children in level two, three and more ...

Comment: Hi @amir nazari ,Thanks for the answer can you give me an example ,so that will be more helpful in Redux ?

Comment: I prefer to use React context API because it is a bit simpler, but if you want to know more about redux this image may help you  [link](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/1103559/Overview.png)